# Adding wysiwyg editor to Magento 2 product attribute options page

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, product-attribute, wysiwyg, tinymce

I have managed to add a custom description field for product attribute options. Now I need to add WYSIWYG editor for the same. My custom module override the default templates for this
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml`

and added new textarea field

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
----
-----
    <td class="hoverarea-col-<%- data.id %>"> 

                    <textarea class="textarea" id="option[hover_area][<%- data.id %>]" name="option[hover_area][<%- data.id %>]" <?php if ($block->getReadOnly() || $block->canManageOptionDefaultOnly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?>><%- data.hover_area %></textarea>
                </td>
-----
--
</script>
```

I tried to add `tinyMCE.init()` function to the template's JS file,but WYSIWYG is not working in these templates.

Can somebody help ?